# Error al guardar en una tabla mySQL con JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo esta clase para guardar en una tabla con JPA:

```
<línea 12>public class AgendaJPADAOImpl implements AgendaJPADAO, Serializable{

EntityManagerFactory emf= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AgendaJPAPU");
EntityManager em= emf.createEntityManager();

@Override
public void guardar(Contacto c) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(c);
    <línea 21>em.getTransaction().commit();
}
}
```

Cada vez que intento guardar en la base de datos me muestra este **stacktrace**:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mysql.contacto' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: INSERT INTO contacto (APELLIDO, CASA, DIRECCION, FECHA, MOVIL, NOMBRE, PERSONAL, TRABAJO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [8 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(comm.agendaJPA.modelo.Contacto@57a86cd2)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
at comm.agendaJPA.dao.impl.AgendaJPADAOImpl.guardar(AgendaJPADAOImpl.java:21)
at comm.agendaJPA.dao.impl.AgendaJPADAOImpl.guardar(AgendaJPADAOImpl.java:12)
at comm.agendaJPA.controlador.AgendaJPAControlador.actionPerformed(AgendaJPAControlador.java:85)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

Me dice que no existe la tabla **contacto**, pero si la tengo creada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Stacktrace también hace referencia a las líneas 21 y 12 de la clase mostrada arriba, marcadas en esta por cierto, y por último la línea 86 de la clase **AgendaJPAControlador**, es aquí donde instancio el método guardar de la clase **AgendaJPADAOImpl**.

```
case getBtnGuardar:
            Contacto c= new Contacto();
            this.agendaJPADAO.guardar(c);
            break;
```

Mi clase **Contacto** esta estructurada de la siguiente manera:

```
package comm.agendaJPA.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "Contactom")
@Table(name = "contacto")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "AgendaJPA.getAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Contactom c")
})
public class Contacto implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar fecha;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private int movil;
private int casa;
private String personal;
private String trabajo;
private String direccion;

public Contacto() {

}

public Contacto(Calendar fecha, String nombre, String apellido, int movil, int casa, String personal, String trabajo, String direccion) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.movil = movil;
    this.casa = casa;
    this.personal = personal;
    this.trabajo = trabajo;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public Contacto(int id, String nombre, String apellido, int movil, int casa,
        String personal, String trabajo, String direccion) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.movil = movil;
    this.casa = casa;
    this.personal = personal;
    this.trabajo = trabajo;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public Calendar getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public int getMovil() {
    return movil;
}

public int getCasa() {
    return casa;
}

public String getPersonal() {
    return personal;
}

public String getTrabajo() {
    return trabajo;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setFecha(Calendar fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public void setMovil(int movil) {
    this.movil = movil;
}

public void setCasa(int casa) {
    this.casa = casa;
}

public void setPersonal(String personal) {
    this.personal = personal;
}

public void setTrabajo(String trabajo) {
    this.trabajo = trabajo;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

}
```

Este es el código del PersistenceUnit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="AgendaJPAPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>comm.agendaJPA.modelo.Contacto</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="itla"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

No se porque me sale esa excepción.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que realmente el PersistenceUnit esté conectando realmente con la BD que crees? El código que muestras parece correcto.

Comment: También lo creo pero ya he cambiado  de proyecto como dos veces, vuelvo hacer otro y copio las clases, y me ocurre lo mismo, déjame poner el XML

Comment: Y puedes insertar en otras tablas correctamente?

Comment: No lo he intentado, pero esa es la única que me interesa insertar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segpun veo en las imágenes que provees, la base de datos a la que quieres conectarte se llama `agenda`, mientras que en tu cadena de conexión indicas que debes ir a la base de datos `mysql`. Cambia tu cadena de conexión en el persistence unit:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
                                                                               ^aquí
```

Comment: Ya lo cambié, ahora me aparece esto "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named AgendaJPAPU at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)"

Comment: Parece que has hecho algún cambio adicional o que tu persistence.xml ha cambiado de ubicación. Asegúrate de que el archivo exista en META-INF en el war generado.

Comment: No lo entiendo, he dejado el persistence.xml como se generó, habría que cambiar la conexión

Comment: Tu persistence.xml se encuentra en tu carpeta META-INF, ¿cierto? ¿Puedes confirmar ese dato por favor?

Comment: Sí, se crea en esa carpeta, crees que debo borrarlo y crearlo nuevamente, causaría algún conflicto eso

Comment: @David qué extraño, se supone que lo podrías actualizar manualmente. Si es necesario, créalo nuevamente, pero considera que la base de datos (esquema) al que apuntas es `agenda`.

Comment: Lo hice de nuevo como dijiste y funciona, gracias por tu continua ayuda.

Comment: De nada. Puedes agradecer mejor marcando esta respuesta como aceptada.